# Bash ${var:-default} equivalent in Python?

Tags: python

What's the simplest way to perform default variable substitution?

```
x = None
... (some process which may set x)
if x is None: use_x = "default"
else:         use_x = x
```

Is there any way of writing this in one line?

Answer (score 11):

You can use a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
use_x = "default" if x is None else x
```

You  could  use a dict defaulting to x if the key did not exist to resemble the bash syntax  but the conditional would be the idiomatic way:

```
use_x = {None: "default"}.get(x, x)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
x = x or "default"
```

in Python. This is not exactly the same, since it depends on Python definition of [truth values](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), which differs from Bash’s distinction of set and unset values. But it’s a close approximation and the *idiomatic* Python way of solving the same general problem of testing for unset values.

If you are *specifically* interested in only substituting `None` values, then this code will yield the wrong result, and Padraic’s solution is more appropriate.

Comment: That's not the same thing, a lot of things are considered false in a boolean context in python. This *might* work, but first you have to ask for clarification.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath While I agree that they are not the same, this is the *idiomatic* way of solving the same problem. I think it’s more helpful to the OP in practice than a theoretical discussion.

Comment: indeed, this will not work if x equals, says, to 0. I really want to check for None value